# Are android apps run in emulator just for testing purposes?

Tags: android, web-applications, android-emulator, emulation

I created a back office corporate tablet android app. Now the client wants the same app in a browser so users on a desktop can have the same functionality.

Can I just use an emulator for this? I.e. setup an android emulator on the users' laptops? Or are emulators not for production use but rather just for testing?

So can I use an emulator or do I need to develop a Web app?

Answer (score 0):

Can I just use an emulator for this?

NO

Or are emulators not for production use but rather just for testing?

YES

Comment: Thanks! That was quick! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 Can I just use an emulator for this?

Yes! But hardware needs to be pretty beefy you have to test it. And don't use standard Android emulator use genymotion instead it's fast, very fast.

## 2 Or are emulators not for production use but rather just for testing?

No! There is a lot of such use. Look at genymotion or bluestack.

*note genymotion runs on virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use emulator for this. Also emulators are mainly just for testing. Many features do not work on emulators.

You will have to build a similar app to work on desktops :)